# How to let wrapped lines insert baselines

Tags: baseline

I want to enclose two elements within a box vertically, and have the baseline of the higher line within that box vertically aligned with the baseline outside. I have the following code to do this:

```
\def \mybox #1#2{\leavevmode \vtop {
    \let ~\hfil
    \lineskiplimit -10000\p@
    \halign {##\cr
    \omit #1\cr
    \omit #2\cr
}}}
```

but whenever I consecutively use this box beyond a single line and makes it wrap, baselineskip does not seem to be inserted between the lines. This is shown in the picture below by the red marking.

[image]

How can I let it follow the ordinary baseline skip?

Comment: That's perfectly normal: your `\vtop` has large depth, so `\lineskip` glue is inserted, because the sum of “previous depth” and “current height” exceeds the baseline skip. You have to set a larger `\baselineskip` for this kind of paragraphs. Can you show a full (minimal) example?

Comment: @egreg Instead of inserting a space based on baselineskip, is there a way to set a minimum space between the bottom of the previous line and the top of the next line?

Comment: Set a larger `\lineskip` glue; the default is 1pt. A minimal example would still be useful for experimenting.

Comment: the fact that the second line has no descenders is surely also involved.  adding a `\strut` at the beginning and end of that line would help some.

Comment: @egreg Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician No example, no answer.